# Oscillating Ruler

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

I was bored in the office and stuck a ruler in my desk and started maing it oscillate. I noticed that when I looked at it from the top, there were some bands of color I observed (as in the pic below)
[image: oscillating ruler pic]

Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: Are you talking about e.g. the yellow stripe that runs down the center of the oscillation?

Comment: That and the slight bluish-purple towards the edges

Comment: an effect of different degrees of light refraction? E.g. there is a change in the optical densities at different points of the ruler as it oscillates.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that the ruler would be refracting light? But how could the metal be refracting it?

Comment: I thought this was a clear plastic ruler sorry. Perhaps its an optical illusion!

Comment: It wouldn't be an optical illusion if it were caught on camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have florescent lights in the office. They are varying in color and brightness at 60 hertz. The width of the yellowish band represents the time the lights are "dimmer".

Comment: A bit late but it seems like the most probable answer haha!